# White listing certain HTML tags in python?

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Let's say `allowed_bits = ['a', 'p']`

```
re.compile(r'<(%s)[^>]*(/>|.*?</\1>)' % ('|'.join(allowed_bits)))
```

matches:

```
<a href="blah blah">blah</a>
<p />
```

and not:

```
<html>blah blah blah</html>
```

What I  want to do is turn it on its head, so that it matches

```
<html>blah blah</html>
<script type="text/javascript">blah blah</script>
```

and not:

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

My thinking was to do something like:

```
re.compile(r'<(**^**%s)[^>]*(/>|.*?</\1>)' % ('|'.join(allowed_bits)))
```

but this doesn't work.

Any ideas? I want to negatively match.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse [X][HT]ML. It can never work reliably. Especially don't ever use regex to filter HTML tags as a security measure. Use a proper XML or HTML parser (eg. BeautifulSoup).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [negative lookahead assertion `(?! … )`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead):

```
re.compile(r'<(?!%s)[^>](/>|.?)' % ('|'.join(allowed_bits)))
```